# getting parameters from url

Tags: php, html, sql

iam trying to make a php function that take the parameters from the url and insert it into database
i tried examining it by typing "http://acstracking.com/dat.php?lat=0&lng=0" in the url but there is no insertion happens what can be the problem?

```
<?php

$Lat = $_GET['lat'];        //Get Latitude Data
$Long = $_GET['lng'];       // Get Longitude Data
$type = "restaurant";          //marker type
$name = "A.C.S";                //Name
$add= "Bahrain";

$dbName = "uobtrack_acstracking"; //Database name

$db = mysql_connect ("localhost","username", "password") or die("Unable To Connect "); //Connect to database

$test= mysql_select_db ($dbName,$db) or die("Unable to select database"); //Test Connection

$query = "INSERT INTO `uobtrack_acstracking`.`markers` (`name`, `address`, `lat`, `long`, `type`) VALUES ('$name', '$add', '$Lat', '$Long', '$type');"; //Insert Query

$Alpha  = @mysql_query($query,$db); //Execute Query

if($Alpha)  
echo "<br> insertion succeeded...";
else
echo "<br> insertion failed...";

mysql_close($db); //Close Connection
}
?>
```

Comment: any errors seen? though not to say but directly inserting user input data into DB can be a big mistake and I would recommend using PDO library with proper binding so that there is no chance of injection.

Comment: remove the @ from @mysql_query to see the error messages. Also use echo mysql_errno($db) . ": " . mysql_error($db) . "\n"; to print mysql errors.

Comment: the mysql-lib is deprecated since PHP 5.5.0. So better use mysqli (e.g. mysqli_query()). Addtionally your query is vulerable to SQL-Injection as you directly use the user input!

Remove the @ in front of the query to get some error message for debugging. Did you check for type compability? You input all values as string. Might be a problem if you defined (e.g.) the lat-field as integer.

Comment: i tried adding 
echo mysql_errno($db) . ": " . mysql_error($db) . "\n"; 
and removing the @ but still i get a blank page with nothing in the screen
what can i do?

Answer (score 0):

I have found that MySql is very buggy when using variables in your statements (also prone to SQL injection). I would recommend using PDO. It is quite easy to learn and allows you to use prepared statements. You can adapt the example below to fit your needs:

```
$opt = array(
  PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
  // other options 
);

$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=yourDatabse;charset=utf8', 'yourUsername', 'yourPassword', $opt);
```

The `$opt` is for error reporting

```
try {
  $sql= "INSERT INTO `table`(`column1`, `column2`) VALUES(:exampleX, :trialX)"; 
  $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->bindParam(':exampleX', $example, PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt->bindParam(':trialX', $trial, PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt->execute();

} catch(PDOException $ex) {
  echo "An Error occured!"; //user friendly message
  echo ($ex->getMessage());
}
```

The `try {...} catch {...}` acts as a way to show errors. When you see `:something` this is a parameter which enables you to have a variable in a statement. The reason for not using the variable name in the parameter (`$stmt->bindParam(':trialX', $trial, PDO::PARAM_STR);` instead of `$stmt->bindParam(':trial', $trial, PDO::PARAM_STR);` is when I asked s similar question, the told me not to use a variable name for a parameter name.

This may seem really complicated (still is for me) but I hope it answers your question.

Comment: thanks this really helped me thanks alot for your effort and time :D